# Does Google Sheets have a 'Tag' system

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I am making a google sheet showing details about a set of TCG cards and I would like to be able to filter the table to easily find cards that fit a specific criteria. With something like the cards colour this is easy because you can simply filter by the value of the colour column, but I would like a solution to make more complex filtering possible.

What I am picturing is a 'tag' system similar to what the Stack Exchange website has where you click a rows tag and are shown all other rows with the same tag. A row can have many tags, or none.
An example is a card might say "Search your deck for a card that costs 3 or less" so I will create a tag called '3 or less', then assign this tag to all cards that do cost 3 or less, as well as more expensive cards that have the same text. Clicking this tag will show all cards with the tag, so it will achieve a different result than simply filtering by cost.

Does Sheets have a function that can do this?

Here is a link to the sheet, if that helps
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LhIfHTvo3qED2C0UgXDw2EiyoFfWBOSbo5UZUQvxV9c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. No, Google Sheets hasn't a built-in function like this but it could be extended by using Google Apps Scripts and add-ons. Unfortunately questions asking for recommendations are off-topic on this site. You might try [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: You can use the FILTER function to find either all rows or all columns that match a set of conditions within an array, though that might be overkill for what you seem to be trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to decide which rows to show is to use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681). You can save filter views and give them descriptive names.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.

Comment: This works perfectly, Thanks